# what is the fastest way to extract all frames from video in python?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have about 100 video that I want to extract the frames from them and store them as images for latter processing and what I noticed is simple way using OpenCV VideoCapture is very slow so my question:

what is the fastest way to read all video frames in python? preferably simple way I mean not complicated

Please note that I do not have access to extra hardware like second processor

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you want to extract frames offline, you can do it using the VLC media player.

Comment: @dhanushka how to that?